# Result of a collapse as input of a query in OpenSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I want to retrieve the documents in an OpenSearch index such that their field `field_1` matches one of the N first distinct values of `field_1`, sorted alphabetically. For instance, with N = 2, I have:

```
{
  "size": 2,
    "collapse" : {
        "field" : "field_1.keyword" 
    },
    "sort": [
             {"field_1.keyword": "asc"}], 
    "from":0,
    "_source": ["field_1"]
}
```

From that, I get the result like:

```
{
  "took": 8,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 10000,
      "relation": "gte"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test_prod",
        "_id": "0O_ozosBTo6XkGJI2Re_",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "field_1": "v1"
        },
        "fields": {
          "field_1.keyword": [
            "v1"
          ]
        },
        "sort": [
          "v1"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "test_prod",
        "_id": "qO_ozosBTo6XkGJI2Re_",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "field_1": "v2"
        },
        "fields": {
          "field_1.keyword": [
            "v2"
          ]
        },
        "sort": [
          "v2"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now, I would like to get these two values of `field_1`, that is,  *v1* and *v2*, and run a query such that retrieves all the documents for which `field_1` is one of those two values.

I would, of course, run a script with any other language that executes one query, retrieves its result and uses it to compose another query, but I would like to know if there is a way that I can do this in a petition, with a single call to OpenSearch.

Comment: It is not possible. You need to make another call that is the only option.